# Set dark style for activity when processing longer tasks

Tags: android

If I open a progress dialog the current activity visually goes to background (it gets darker). I also want to use this visual feedback (style) if I am working on longer running background tasks but without using a progress dialog. Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you are doing something time consuming then you should indicate this with an indeterminate dialog (the one with a spinning wheel) along with a message explaining what you are doing. Otherwise the user will be confused about what is going on.

If you absolutely refuse to show the dialog, you could re-create the dark background by having a transparent view that covers the entire activity and then setting its background colour to a translucent black to make what is behind it appear darker.

Comment: You can see how they did it by looking at the `show()` method in the `Dialog.java` [source code](http://netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Dialog.java).

Comment: I give the feedback with `getParent().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);` - as the background process normally does not last verly long a full progressDialog is to heavy. Thanks for your tip. I will check it tomorrow. +1 for the moment.